# Server certificate/domain custom validation when connecting via TLS/SSL on production

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

The error below occurs when a web service request is sent to a remote web service:

> ```
> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
> ```

My question:

1 Is the code below combined with TLS/SSL still safe to use on **production** given the server is in our control. Think of attack like man-in-the-middle, and others.

2 What about if the server is not in our control, can the validation prove secure?

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (
    object sender,
    X509Certificate cert,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;   //Is valid
    }

    //validate Server's certificate or Server's domain name or IP
    if (IsValidServerCertificate(cert) || 
        IsValidServerIP(cert))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

   public bool IsValidServerCertificate(X509Certificate cert){
    return cert.GetCertHashString() == "server's public certificate thumbprint")
   }
    public bool IsValidServerIP(){
     //compare server's ip address from the request with the address we are given" 
   }
```

The proper way is to login using server's public certificate from client side, but what validation this method provides that my custom validation need to add?

**Update:**

For whose who voted down the ticket: If you know the solution, why cannot you provide it. There is no solution in code on SO.

I believe this ticket can benefit someone else in the future, if a simple solution with code sample can be found.

Comment: It’s impossible to answer this question because the second if statement is not valid C#. The only way we could determine if this is “safe” is if you actually include the actual code you are using here. That said, almost certainly what you have done is not safe.

Comment: The if statement is pseudo-code. I can update that to avoid confusion.

Comment: "The proper way is to login using server's public certificate from client side" During the handshake of one side SSL, it is the client who receives the server's certificate and then verify as [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f34e088ff8400ff39ceff5a68b3b1a90dbe8d0ab/src/System.Net.Security/src/System/Net/Security/SecureChannel.cs#L971) by default by Microsoft. Two-side SSL adds a step to send client certificate to server for verification. The client **never** sends the server's certificate. Like I commented elsewhere, if you don't learn the ABCs, meaningless to discuss further.

Comment: I was given a Server's public certificate (.Cer), I am not aware of client certificate for client to use.

Comment: Even with your changes, the question is no clearer. The security of your implementation depends entirely on `IsValidServerCertificate` and `IsValidServerIP`, which you have omitted. However, if the implementation of `IsValidServerIP` simply checks the IP against some hard-coded value (which seems impossible since you only pass a certificate to the method,  from which you’d have no way to determine the actual server IP), then this approach is most definitely **NOT** secure.

Comment: Please see update. IsValidServerIP  checks the ip against hard-code value, which is  given to connect to the server in the first place.

Comment: "For whose who voted down the ticket: If you know the solution, why cannot you provide it." This is wrong to put in your question, please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

> ... safe to use on production given the server is in our control. Think of attack like man-in-the-middle, and others.

Man in the middle attacks are not attacks at the client nor at the server but in the middle. Therefore it does not matter at all if the server is in your control. You could only be sure that no man in the middle attacks occur if everything between client and server would be in your control too. And to achieve this you have to make sure that the client is even using the path you control: things like DNS spoofing might return in a different destination IP address and thus in a different path than you expect.

In other words: **the code is unsafe, no matter if you control the server or not**. It should not be used in production. Instead of trying to work around broken setups you should fix the cause of the problem. These are usually broken certificates, incomplete chain or broken setup of trust anchors.

Comment: The proper way is to login using server's public certificate from client side, but what validation this method provides that my custom validation need to add?

Comment: @Pingpong: you essentially ask how the validation of a server certificate is done. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity). The main points: it exists a trust path to a local trust anchor, the subject/SAN matches the expectation, it is not expired and not revoked.